# How to check the Internet connection before loading a page?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

Before loading a page, I want to check the Internet connection in Xamarin. But I get a problem of this type:

> 06-21 14: 48: 59.072 E / mono-rt (11985): / proc / self / maps: Got a
>   SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
>   error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used by your
>   application.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;

namespace ConnectBDD
{
public partial class PageLecture : ContentPage 
{

public PageLecture()
{
InitializeComponent();

        //permet de rafraichir les données dans la "listeView" via une action 
        monViews.RefreshCommand = new Command((obj) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("refresh command");
            DownloadData((articles) =>
            {
                monViews.ItemsSource = articles;
                monViews.IsRefreshing = false;
            });
        });

        //Appel de la fonction de téléchargement + passage de Paramètre avec la fonction invoke
        DownloadData((articles) =>
            {
                monViews.ItemsSource = articles;
                monViews.IsVisible = true;
                waitLayout.IsVisible = false;
            });

        // permet d'afficher une description en cliquant sur les cellules de la liste
        monViews.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // si cellule est active la condition est rempli
            if (monViews.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                // assigne item pour selection des données de la liste
                Article item = monViews.SelectedItem as Article;

                // Affiche un message si tu appui sur une cellule de la liste
                DisplayAlert(item.Nom, item.Description, "Ok");
                //si la valeur n'est pas null la cellule sera bloqué si on repush dessus
                monViews.SelectedItem = null;
            }
        };

    }
    private void DownloadData(Action<List<Article>> action)
    {
        // renseigne le liens de téléchargement du JSON avec une constante
        const string URL = "#######";

        //instance du webclient - Cas particulier pour cette appel, ça ce fait uniquement avec un using - (La tache sera détruite de la mémoire dès qu'elle sera terminé !)         

        Console.WriteLine("ETAPE 1");

        using (var webclients = new WebClient())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ETAPE 2");

            // Prépare le téléchargement du fichier JSON - Asynchrone
            Console.WriteLine("ETAPE 3");
            webclients.DownloadStringCompleted += (object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) =>
            {

                string linkJson = "";
                try
                {
                    linkJson = e.Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Données téléchargées");
                }
                catch (WebException wex)
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        DisplayAlert("Erreur", "Il y a un problème : " + wex.Message, "OK");
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        DisplayAlert("Erreur", "Il y a un problème : " + ex.Message, "OK");
                    });
                }
                // Convertir JSON en Objet
                //List<Article> articles; //en lien avec la class "Article" Génère une Liste et on passe celà dans la variables liste "articles"
                List<Article> articles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Article>>(linkJson);

                // Et on revient sur la Mainthread pour sortir les données dans le XAML
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                    // renvoie dans le XAML les données "articles" en lien avec x:Name "monViews" définis dans "listViews"
                    action.Invoke(articles); //permet le renvoi de paramètre via l'invoke
                    Console.WriteLine("ETAPE 5");

                    });
            };
            Console.WriteLine("ETAPE 4");
            webclients.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(URL));
        }
    }
}

}
```

It works on emulator Andoid Pie 9, but not on my Huawei P8 lite 2017!

Creating a network check before loading the page would be the simplest solution, except that I do not know the functions that allows me this verification. Microsoft documentation does not help much!

Do you have any ideas how to check the Internet connection in Xamarin before loading a page?

Comment: So, your question is how to check Connectivity in Xamarin?

Comment: To Bruno Caceiro:
yes I would like to check internet connections before loading a page.

To Owen Pauling:
I'm afraid that since 2010 this method has changed, but I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check internet connection in a Xamarin project with [Xamarin Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/) plugin.

In details you need the [Connectivity API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=ios).

So, first install the [Xamarin.Essentials nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials/)

Then add the namespace:

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
```

Now you can check the internet connection:

```
var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
{
    // Connection to internet is available
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this lesson, it works!
Thank you ! GiampaoloGabba

private static bool CheckConnection()
        {
            bool testConnection;
            var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;
            if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
                testConnection = true;
                return testConnection;
            }
            else
            {
                testConnection = false;
                return testConnection;
            }
        }